# Passing data on microframe stm32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, hid, stm32cubeide

I am trying to get an 8kHz polling rate mouse (I don't know if polling rate is the right word though), and the only problem I have come a cross is the speed of HID. I am using USB 2.0 HS. My microcontroller is the [STM32H733VGT6](https://estore.st.com/en/stm32h733vgt6-cpn.html) and the product page is [here](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h733vg.html#overview).
What I want to do is to take advantage of microframes and transmit data every 0.125ms (every microframe). This would lead to 8kHz polling rate. I have done some research and have found this property: [USBD_HID_HS_WMAXPACKETSIZE](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/rlarm/rlarm_usb_config_hid.htm#:%7E:text=Additional%20transactions%20per,configures%20this%20macro), but there is no default implementation in STM32CubeIDE, and code generation will override anything I add. (Also, I have no idea how to implement this  :D)

To clarify:
I would like to take advantage of microframes to send HID data at a rate of 8kHz to the computer. I would also like to be able to edit that data in the 0.125 seconds before the next microframe. How would I implement this in C??

Comment: The MCU does not have a built-in HS PHY but requires an external ULPI connected HS PHY chip. Are you absolutely sure your board has one?

Comment: @Justme I’m doing the board myself in KiCAD, so I can add one.